# What protective device can be used to avoid no-load operation in a dc series motor?

Tags: motor, relay, dc, series, solid-state-devices

I think there must be some relay or converter which automatically shuts the machine on no load condition.
( **Just Guessing** )

The following para is a quora answer which I am not sure is correct, please share your thoughts-
**You can modify it  by putting resistor in parallel to armature winding, such that will draw current. So now field current = armature + external resistor current.**

Comment: Are you worried about excessive speed? Do you have a data sheet for the motor?

Comment: Actually this question was in my assignment. I have no data sheet.

Comment: I googled it and try to see any thread or quora answer but all that was we cannot use dc series motor in no load condition. There was nothing about any device to avoid such condition.

Comment: Please link to the page where it said "we cannot use dc series motor in no load condition".

Comment: we can use it but eventually it will damage the motor

Comment: The quote from Quora lacks context (wording of related question). Putting a resistor in parallel with the armature would reduce the maximum speed somewhat. You would need to consider how much power you would need to waste to achieve what you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks everyone for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinarily, it is not necessary to protect a series motor against no-load operation. The motor's own mechanical losses will be sufficient to prevent the motor from operating at a speed that would cause damage. If the driven machine requires protection from excessive speed, a centrifugal switch can be used shut the motor off when an above-normal speed is reached.

Comment: Can't we do some modification so that at no load the dc series motor behave as dc shunt motor which can be operate in no load condition?

Comment: I doubt it would be practical to change the motor characteristics based on load. Compound motors have characteristics between shunt and series motor characteristics. In my opinion we are talking about details of machines that have not been used in demanding applications for more than 50 years.

Comment: Not uncommon in some textbooks / coursework unfortunately... Load up students with superfluous information that has no relevant practical use in the real world, but the students will not find that out until after they get there. I remember having to learn all about DC Series Motor runaway conditions in 3 days of classes, now after 40+ years in the field, I have yet to encounter a DC series wound motor. That's 3 days of my life I want back.